# How to redirect to SSO page after logout?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a webapp that is hosted in AWS, when the user acess the url the loadbalancer redirect him to SSO, `https://login-int.fabricafic.com/?instance=default&resumePath=%2Fas%2FI53nNxOR8T%2Fresume%2Fas%2Fauthorization.ping&allowInteraction=true&reauth=false&connectionId=eert80-7nn5-iii6-9966-070bbbf24353c&REF=6683754F172F09DSFJV034M105C4F4872F0BBDSFG4440001F4&unique_id=P123gj5Tsd98123n9&AWGWiPfBwAAANo&scope=openid&client_id=eert80-7nn5-iii6-9966-070bbbf24353c&dc=em1` and the user enter with his credentials and is redirected to Index page.
There are a logout button, that i'm trying to exclude de cookies and redirect him back to SSO. but i dont know how. Someone can help?

That's my code

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken", out var accesstoken);
    Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-amzn-oidc-identity", out var identity);
    Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-amzn-oidc-data", out var oidc);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identity))
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        foreach (var key in Request.Cookies.Keys)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
        }

        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

    var usuarioParaLogin = await _autorizacaoService.VerificarSeUsuarioEstaAutorizado(identity);

    if (!usuarioParaLogin.Valido)
    {
        _notyf.Error(usuarioParaLogin.Mensagem);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Helth");
    }

    await AutenticacaoHelper.AutenticarNoCookie(identity, usuarioParaLogin, HttpContext);  

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { identity = identity, oidc = oidc });
}


 [HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
}
```